# How to save todo list data with local storage through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Here I am only using javascript.

HTML:

```
<section class="notes-section">
            <div class="layout clearfix">
                <input id="user_input" name="user_input" placeholder="Enter your new note" type="text" />
                <button value="Add" id="add" onclick="addNotes()">New</button>
                <ul id="note_List" class="notes-block"></ul>
            </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function addNotes() {
    var input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
    if (input == "") {
        window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
    }
    else {
        var noteList = document.getElementById('note_List');
         noteList.innerHTML += "<li><span>" + input + "</span><button onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)' class='delete'>Delete</button> <button class='edit' onclick='this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.contentEditable = true;' >Edit</button></li>";

    }
}
</script>
```

I am sharing fiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/o2mLgd67/
If anyone can update the code,then it will be helpful.

I have tried this below code:

```
(function() {

  var demo = document.querySelector('.notes-block');
  function supportsLocalStorage() {
    return typeof(Storage)!== 'undefined';
  }
  if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {
    demo.value = 'No HTML5 localStorage support, soz.';

  } else {

      setInterval(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.value);
      }, 1000);


    if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
      demo.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
      alert("hi");
    }

  }

})();
```

But its not helping me.

Comment: Have you tried to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: Yes tried above code. But its showing that autosave is undefined.

Comment: Sunniya Maini. why dont you accept my updated answer? didn't it help you?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get value from localStorage before you set it.

setInterval is asynchronize process, so - the 'set' statement called after 1000 ms, but the get - is called immediently. You must change it, Try:

```
       setInterval(function() {
localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.value);

   if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
      demo.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
       alert("hi");
   }
     }, 1000);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

OK,
I correct your jsFiddle to use 'demo.innerHTML' instead of 'demo.value' and it works well!!

see:   https://jsfiddle.net/o2mLgd67/7/

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.innerHTML);
       demo.innerHTML = "";
         setTimeout(function() {

     if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
  demo.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
  alert(demo.innerHTML);
} }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Checked your fiddle. But its not working as per my need. On click of new button, data is hiding, refreshing. I want todo list like feature. Data should always appear on page even after closing browser.

Comment: I'm afraid your browser remove history automatically. wich browser do you use?

Comment: Okay.But I have all browsers, firefox, chrome, safari, IE11.

Comment: On IE - check at tools --> internetoptions-->, and uncheck checkbox 'Delete browsing history on exit'. search this cb at other browsers. Notice, at chrome - this problem not exist.

Comment: Also, I recommend you to attach your entire solution. The info which you attached is not enough. We must see why doesn't it works - it is really simply task.